# chartjs cutoutPercentage and tooltips does not works in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I have this code in my next.js project where I am using the react-chartjs-2 library to create charts. the cutoutPercentage property in chart.js theoretically makes the donut chart thinner, but in next.js it doesn't work.
how can I make it to work?

```
import { Doughnut  } from 'react-chartjs-2';

const data = {
  datasets: [
    {
      data: [15, 12, 40, 30],
      backgroundColor: ["#c5e99b", "#8fbc94", "#548687", "#56445d"],
    },
  ],
};

const Options = {
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    cutoutPercentage: 70,
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
}

export default () => (
    <Doughnut 
      data={data}
      width={290}
      height={290}
      options={Options}
    />
);
```

Comment: does it show an error on server that document/window is undefined ?

Comment: no there is no error on server or client

Comment: Give export comp a name and use this to import component. const DynamicComponentWithNoSSR = dynamic(() => import('../components/hello3'),{ ssr: false })

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined `Options` for Chart.js version 2.x but you most probably use Chart.js version 3.x, that's why it doesn't work.

Please take a look at the [3.x Migration Guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/next/getting-started/v3-migration.html) in order to find out, what options have changed. In your case, the following points are relevant:

- `tooltips` namespace was renamed to `tooltip` to match the plugin name.
- Doughnut `cutoutPercentage` was renamed to `cutout` and accepts pixels as numer and percent as string ending with `%`.

Accordingly, you need to change your `Options` as follows:

```
const Options = {
  plugins: {
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false,
    }
  },
  cutout: '70%',
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
}
```